# Handling MongoDB Errors depending on it's type

Tags: mongodb, go, error-handling

I am getting the data of an account using the ID of it. Currently, when I make this query the mongo-go-driver gives an error and I want to handle this error differently, depending on its type. For example if the document doesn't exist I want to return a 404 but lets suppose that the instance holding my mongodb falls, in this case I want to return a 500. How can I handle the error type:

```
func (dao MongoDAO) Get(ctx *gin.Context, filter bson.M, entity interface{}) error {
    context, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    if err := dao.Collection.FindOne(context, filter).Decode(entity); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Error variables defined in the mongo-go-driver docs (https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo?tab=doc#pkg-variables). With these you might be able to do something like this:

```
func (dao MongoDAO) Get(ctx *gin.Context, filter bson.M, entity interface{}) error {
    context, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    if err := dao.Collection.FindOne(context, filter).Decode(entity); err != nil {
        if err == mongo.ErrNoDocuments {
            // Return the 404
        }
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```